# Optimize jQuery code

Tags: jquery, optimization

Greetings,

Just built some stuff with jQuery, everything works perfect(!), but I would like it to be as optimzed as possible.. what small changes can I do to my code?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

 // hide the indicator, we use it later
 $(".indicator").hide();

 // start the animation of the progressbar 
 $(".fill").animate({ width: "50px",}, 4000, function() { $(".indicator").effect("pulsate", { times:999 }, 2000);});

 // notify-me ajax function
 $(".btn-submit").click(function() {  

  // get the variable email and put it in a new variable
  var email = $("input#mail").val();   
  var dataString = 'mail='+email;

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/mail.php",
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(msg){

    // JSON return, lets do some magic
    if(msg.status == "ok") { 
     $("#response-box").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
     $("#fade").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
     $("#response-box .inner").html("<h1>Thank you.</h1>We'll keep in touch!");
     $("#mail").val("e.g. name@example.com");
    } else { 
     $("#response-box").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
     $("#fade").fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
     $("#response-box .inner").html("<h1>Oops.</h1>Please try again!");
    }
   }
  });

  //make sure the form doesn't post
  return false;

 });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two principal things in your code that I would change:

First: `dataString = 'mail='+email;` This is not the best way to set this request parameter. `email` could easily contain characters that should be encoded when put into a HTTP request. You could do this by using [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
dataString = jQuery.param({mail: email});
```

This will encode characters that have special meaning in an HTTP request, and should make the code more reliable.  Alternatively, and slightly faster, you could use the native JS function [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
datastring = 'mail=' + encodeURIComponent(email);
```

Second, you are using `return false` to avoid the default action occuring.  I prefer to use [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).  This is firstly stylistic -- it makes it more clear what you are intending to achieve; secondly, you can put it at the beginning of your handler function.  Therefore, if you have an error in the rest of your function for whatever reason, the default action is still prevented.

There may be some other enhancements that could be achieved in terms of the selectors, but it is impossible to tell without seeing your HTML.

Comment: +1 All points are valid, no unnecessary micro-optimization tip.

Comment: cant he just use `$('form_id').serialize()`?

Comment: @ifaour That could be a performance regression if the only thing you want to encode was the email address and there was more to the form.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Thank you for the tip! I noticed that I had to add event in the button click function ($(".btn-submit").click(function(event) {)  to be able to use the event.preventDefault, else Firefox didn't post the form.

Comment: Hmm... one last "issue".. To be able to use the pulsate effect i have to include both jQuery and jQuery UI Libraries from Google Libraries API, is there any workaround here?

Comment: @Dannemannen You only need to install the core effects and pulsate components, so you could load a customised file from [this page](http://jqueryui.com/download) if you preferred. However, using the Google CDN will allow your users to use previously cached versions of jQuery UI. It's probably about even, IMO.